# Need alternative approach for executing a SQL query into loop

Tags: java, mysql, swing

**Problem:** One of my client's requirement is to receive orders from the client (Stored in txnorder table) and generate packing slips against them (Stored in txnpackingslip table). Now Sometimes there are more items packed than ordered which is not an issue, the problem arises when I've to generate a report for Packing more than order (Referenced as Negative Orders). There are more than 1400 customers, more than 300 rows are updated daily in the txnorder table and more than 250 rows in txnpacking slip table.
the MySQL server is centralized on a web hosting.

**What I've Done:** I've already written a Stored Procedure as below, but with centralized server it is taking more than 90 seconds to extract results while the row count of order table is 1600 and packinslip 1400

**Stored Procedure:** `

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `NegativeOrders`(
    IN pcinput INT
    )
BEGIN
    SELECT 
    DISTINCT(o.ocode) AS "Code", 
    o.opcode, (o.obdl - IFNULL(p.pbdl,0)) AS "Req_Bdl", 
    (o.obox - IFNULL(p.pbox,0)) AS "Req_Box" 
    FROM 
        (SELECT DISTINCT(orderprdcode) AS ocode,
        orderpartycode AS opcode, (SUM(orderbdl)) AS obdl, 
        (SUM(orderbox)) AS obox 
        FROM txnorder WHERE orderpartycode = pcinput 
        GROUP BY orderprdcode) o 
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT DISTINCT(packprodcode) AS pcode, 
        packpartycode AS ppcode, 
        (SUM(packbdl)) AS pbdl, 
        (SUM(packbox)) AS pbox 
        FROM txnpackingslip WHERE packpartycode = pcinput
        GROUP BY packprodcode) p 
    ON o.ocode = p.pcode  
    GROUP BY o.ocode 
    HAVING req_bdl < 0 OR req_box < 0;

    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

This is the SQL Fiddle Created : [NegativeOrderFiddle](http://db-fiddle.com/f/9CuoNzqiE8VfkYB24E2WcU/0)

**Note:** I'm open to adapt any relevant approach other than optimizing my SQL

Comment: Try digging through the execution plan which will hopefully provide hints on how to optimize.  Also, this doesn't appear to be related to java.

Comment: ... this sounds like it's a problem of hardware, not software. The numbers you state are next to nothing, if that takes a minute and a half to process, the environment the database is running in is severely restricted.

Comment: Your execution plan may suggest that you need specific indices. Add them!

Comment: I tagged java because the result of this query need to be displayed in a jTable.
also if there is any possibility of caching a resultset into java and executing operations over there, I'm open to adapt them too.
As Suggested by @Gimby, I tried it on different servers and the query takes almost same time everywhere as I've to execute this query for almost 1000 customers. So basically I'm Executing a SQL Stored Procedure in loop for 1000 times.